# Bind function( with parameters) to click event with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, onclick

This works:

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">Help!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Jquery:

```
function myfunction( c1 ) {
    $("#mydiv").css({'background-color': 'blue' });
}

$("#mydiv").on('click',  myfunction );
```

I understand that using () immediately after a function calls that function.

So...

How can I bind a function to a click, and pass parameters at the same time?

HTML:

```
<div id="mydiv">Help!</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Jquery:

```
function myfunction( c1 ) {
    $("#mydiv").css({'background-color': c1 });
}

$("#mydiv").on('click',  myfunction("blue") );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can wrap the call in a function expression, and use the `call` method to set the context for the call as the context in the event handler:

```
$("#mydiv").on('click', function(){ myfunction.call(this, "blue"); });
```

Comment: Thank you! I was messing around with a fiddle trying to get this to work before i realized i didn't have a jquery library selected. Your answer works, and for future readers i'll say that this also works . . . . . . . . . . . . . . .$("#mydiv").on('click', function(){ myfunction("blue") });

Comment: @RedBeardPro: Yes, that works as long as you don't use `this` in the function to access the element where the event happened.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery on event binding function has a 'data' parameter. 
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )

http://jsfiddle.net/aNDgC/101/

```
$('#myButton').on("click", {name: "world"} , function(event){
    $('#divOutput').html(event.data.name);
});
```